# JavaFX Tab fit full size of header

Tags: css, javafx, tabs, size

I want the tabs in my tabpane to fit the complete size of the tabpane which they are in. So basically there shall be no header area visible, everything should be covered by the tabs.

I have 2 problems here:

- How can I make the tabs dynamically fit the width of the tabpane?
- How can I fit them to the correct height, and remove the little spaces between the tabs? I suppose this is done via css, but I don't quite know how.

greets

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add a listener to the TabPane to detect any changes and adjust the width and/or height of the tabs accordingly.

```
@FXML
private JFXTabPane tabPane;
```

Divide the width by number of tabs:

```
tabPane.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
    {
        tabPane.setTabMinWidth(tabPane.getWidth() / tabPane.getTabs().size());
        tabPane.setTabMaxWidth(tabPane.getWidth() / tabPane.getTabs().size());      
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

It's true, the property objects of tabs are READ-Only. This means that you cannot manually set the properties. However, the values of the read-only properties can be bound to other properties, also the properties have some manipulation methods e.g. divide, subtract, please check the documentation for extended information.

You can call the `.tabminWidthProperty()` on the tabpane and bind it to the width-property value of the parent of the layout.

Here's the code to size all available tabs equally filling the whole screen:

```
tabpane.tabMinWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(tabpane.getTabs().size()).subtract(20));
```

I subtracted 20 to avoid the horizontal/vertical scrollbar. Surely there is also a way to disable them to pop up at all, but I'm an Android Dev and a greenhorn in JavaFx.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is do-able in CSS, and there might be a simpler way in Java to do this, but I wrote a class that extends TabPane in order to stretch the tabs to fill all the space.

```
public class StretchedTabPane extends TabPane {

    public StretchedTabPane() {
        super();
        setUpChangeListeners();
    }

    public StretchedTabPane(Tab... tabs) {
        super(tabs);
        setUpChangeListeners();
    }

    private void setUpChangeListeners() {

        widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> value, Number oldWidth, Number newWidth) {
                Side side = getSide();
                int numTabs = getTabs().size();
                if ((side == Side.BOTTOM || side == Side.TOP) && numTabs != 0) {
                    setTabMinWidth(newWidth.intValue() / numTabs - (20));
                    setTabMaxWidth(newWidth.intValue() / numTabs - (20));
                }
            }
        });

        heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> value, Number oldHeight, Number newHeight) {
                Side side = getSide();
                int numTabs = getTabs().size();
                if ((side == Side.LEFT || side == Side.RIGHT) && numTabs != 0) {
                    setTabMinWidth(newHeight.intValue() / numTabs - (20));
                    setTabMaxWidth(newHeight.intValue() / numTabs - (20));
               }
           }
        });

        getTabs().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Tab>() {
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Tab> change){
                Side side = getSide();
                int numTabs = getTabs().size();
                if (numTabs != 0) {
                    if (side == Side.LEFT|| side == Side.RIGHT) {
                        setTabMinWidth(heightProperty().intValue() / numTabs - (20));
                        setTabMaxWidth(heightProperty().intValue() / numTabs - (20));
                    }
                    if (side == Side.BOTTOM || side == Side.TOP) {
                        setTabMinWidth(widthProperty().intValue() / numTabs - (20));
                        setTabMaxWidth(widthProperty().intValue() / numTabs - (20));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
   }
}
```

This will automatically adjust the width of each tab when the height, width or number of tabs changes.

Comment: Where did you get these constants from -- 23 and 20? The 20 seems a little off on my system at the moment. I'm sure they were right for some other configuration.

Comment: If I remember correctly, if the tabs were made to fill the whole space, then the last tab will be left off and a drop-down for selecting the tabs will be placed on the end. So the 20 is just a buffer to avoid that, but I admit it might need some tweaking depending on how things look for you.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done directly in fxml file and can be used on any Node no having fitToWidth or fitToHeight property. See small example below, hope it helps somebody.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        fx:controller="somepackage.MainWindowController"
        prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
fx:id="mainPane">
<TabPane prefHeight="${mainPane.height}" prefWidth="${mainPane.width}" style="-fx-background-color: blue">
    <Tab fx:id="someTab">
        <Label text="bla bla">
    </Tab>
</TabPane>
```

I'd like to pinpoint the main part which causes extension of the Tab:

> prefHeight="${mainPane.height}" prefWidth="${mainPane.width}"

Comment: Except that he wants the Tabs to expand to fill the entire TabPane, not the TabPane to fit the container it's in.