# Hide the drop down Arrow of a TabPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to get a Tabpane with two equally big tabs, that fill the whole space. I'm using this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51230536/4917438

```
tabPane.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
{
    tabPane.setTabMinWidth(tabPane.getWidth() / tabPane.getTabs().size());
    tabPane.setTabMaxWidth(tabPane.getWidth() / tabPane.getTabs().size());      
});
```

JavaFX displays a drop-down arrow on the right tab now, however. How can the drop-down arrow be disabled?
I would prefer a solution that works with code, since I currently don't use FXML.
[image: image of TabView]

Comment: the TabPane's skin thinks there is not enough vertical space to show all tabs completely (look at the implementation, it's in tabsFit() of TabHeaderArea) - a hack might be to reduce the tab widths by some pixel. At the end of the day, you would need a custom skin to customize the layout (which is basically trivial .. except that everything is package-/private, so not much leeway to hook in)

Comment: .. _vertical_ should be _horizontal_ ..